executing script in systemctl does not take the arguments
I have a systemctl service which does not take the arguments. It works on the command line, but not within systemctl.
[Service]
Type=forking
User=sunyata
WorkingDirectory=/home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmask
Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmask"
ExecStartPre=/usr/games/steamcmd +force_install_dir /home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmask/ +login anonymous +app_update 3017300 validate +quit
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/soulmaskserver.sh "$(</home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/parameters)"
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -S test -X stuff '^C'

It works when I write down the arguments directly behind soulmaskserver.sh in the systemctl service file. But I have a script which changes the arguments in a file and then the file has to pass the arguments to soulmaskserver.sh when executed from systemctl service.
executing this from the command line works just fine;
/home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/soulmaskserver.sh "$(</home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/parameters)"

Can anyone help and assist in this matter?

systemd unit files are not shell scripts, and the Exec family do not directly support the $(...) command substitution syntax - see for example Use dynamic date in systemd unit

Thanks, I have figured it out. I have used an enviromentfile=file to the service. It works now
